# How can I programmatically monitor the activity on an already opened serial port?

Tags: c#, java

Is there a library or code sample (preferably C# or Java, but not required) that allows to "sniff" what is happening on a serial port which is being used by another application? Like this software does:

http://www.eltima.com/products/serial-port-monitor/

Comment: I think you would need to replace the serial port driver.  Not exactly an easy task.  Also note that there is a certain expectation of "privacy" with respect to such things; if an application has opened a serial port, it does not expect other applications to be sniffing it.

Comment: The expectation on a computer is that nothing is private from the superuser.  I own the machine, I control the machine, I do what I like, and software operates at my behest.  It's DRM technologies trying the change this fundamental fact that tend to screw things up.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You need to alter the driver or write a port emulator to able to do this.

Comment: On most operating systems, you can write a *filter driver* to intercept requests, without having to modify the driver that talks to the hardware.